# Использование Menu Item для ViewPager2

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Всем привет!
Создаю фрагменты в ViewPager2 и хочу сделать меню (BottomNavigationView), с помощью которого можно было бы перелистывать фрагменты.

Меню сейчас выглядит так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navMain"
        android:icon="@drawable/custom_login_icon"
        android:title="Первый фрагмент" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navMyTrips"
        android:icon="@drawable/custom_email_icon"
        android:title="Второй фрагмент" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/navProfile"
        android:icon="@drawable/custom_login_icon"
        android:title="Третий фрагмент" />
</menu>
```

Если делаю перелистывание через TabLayout:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

TabLayoutMediator tabLayoutMediator = new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager,
        new TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy()
        {
            @Override
            public void onConfigureTab(@NonNull TabLayout.Tab tab, int position)
            {
                switch (position)
                {
                    case 0:
                        tab.setText("1");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tab.setText("2");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tab.setText("3");
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
        tabLayoutMediator.attach();
```

Всё проходит корректно, но меня не устраивает внешний вид и другие возможности TabLayout.

BottomNavigationView подходит, но не получается реализовать перелистывание при нажатии на пункт меню.

С меню пытаюсь сделать так:

```
bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);

bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
        new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
            {
                switch (item.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.navMain:
                        replaceFragment(mainFragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navMyTrips:
                        replaceFragment(userProfileFragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navProfile:
                        replaceFragment(userTripsFragment);
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Метод для замены фрагмента:

```
private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.viewPager, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
    t.commit();
}
```

Android Studio ругается на ViewPager2:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPager2 does not support direct child views
```

И насколько я знаю, через FragmentTransaction может проходить замена фрагмента, но без анимации (как у TabLayout при переходе).

Вопрос в том, можно ли использовать Menu Item вместо TabLayout и организовать перелистывание фрагментов по нажатии на кнопку из Menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось сделать так:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item)
                    {
                        switch (item.getItemId())
                        {
                            case R.id.navMain:
                                viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.navMyTrips:
                                viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                                return true;
                            case R.id.navProfile:
                                viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                                return true;
                            default:
                                return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Нашёл [тут](https://droidmentor.com/bottomnavigationview-with-viewpager-android/).

UPD:
Для ViewPager2 (в статье используется ViewPager) и изменения иконки меню при перелистывании:

```
private MenuItem prevMenuItem;

viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position)
            {
                super.onPageSelected(position);

                if (prevMenuItem != null)
                    prevMenuItem.setChecked(false);
                else
                    bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(false);

                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
                prevMenuItem = bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(position);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нет обязательного условия привязывания к ViewPager, то советую изучить рекомендуемую в документации [реализацию](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample) навигации через BottomNavigationView, которая позволяет избежать некоторых проблем, которые возникают в вариации с ViewPager.